# How do I get mushroom blocks to drop when mined?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Whenever I try to break a mushroom block in survival, it doesn't give me the item. Why is this happening? Is there a way I can get the item legitimately in survival?

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes when you break mushroom blocks, they will drop their corresponding mushroom (non-block version).

To drop the blocks themselves, mushroom blocks must be mined with any tool with the **Silk Touch** enchantment.